# [0]=> bool(false) in the end of array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have an array that looks like this:

```
$object = array(filed1=>newvalue1,field2=>newvalue2,field3=>newvalue3);
```

I need to check it with mysql_real_escape_string and pass it to mysql

```
foreach ($object as $key => $value)
    {
        $key = mysql_real_escape_string($key . '');
        $value = mysql_real_escape_string($value . '');
        $object[$key] = $value;
    }
```

In the end it returns the following array:

```
array(4) { 
          ["filed1"]=> string(9) "newvalue1" 
          ["field2"]=> string(9) "newvalue2" 
          ["field3"]=> string(9) "newvalue3" 
          [0]=> bool(false) 
         }
```

How and why the last [0]=> bool(false)  appeared? How do I remove it?

P.S. please, no "use PDO" advices... it is my home assignment and PDO is not an option. Thank you.

Comment: did you var_dump($object) ?

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string` returns false on error

Comment: Though why are you concatenating the keys and values with an empty string?

Comment: I have to caution you against updating the array inside the foreach, this causes PHP to make a new copy of the array on each loop, and is extremely inefficient. Consider using: `foreach ($object as &$key => &$value) { $key = mysql_real_escape_string($key . '');
        $value = mysql_real_escape_string($value . ''); }` instead.

Comment: yes, I used var_dump($object) to see why output was not what I needed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two issues here.

First, `mysql_real_escape_string` requires a connection. If you haven't created one, it would try creating it by calling `mysql_connect` with no parameters, and, should the latter fail, would return a boolean FALSE.

Second, while it seems your intent was to update the original `$object` keys, you're in fact updating those returned by `mysql_real_escape_string`.

```
$key = mysql_real_escape_string($key . '');

// This sets $key to FALSE

$value = mysql_real_escape_string($value . '');

// This sets $value to FALSE

$object[$key] = $value;

// $object[FALSE] = FALSE;
```

The last statement adds the extra entry on the first run and updates it (with the same value) on the next runs.

Comment: thank you. indeed I do not have connection established. it was just a sample code with no db:)

Comment: @metamorph_online: `mysql_escape_string`, a now obsolete function, does not require connection, neither does it escape strings safely (as what exactly to escape depends on connection encoding).